# Codeigniter: JSON data is returned after AJAX call but it cannot run the success: function()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

My Ajax

```js
// Load category function
        function load_category()
        {
          $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/admin/departments",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
              $('#category-row').html(data);
            },
            error: function(){
              alert('Error....');
            }
          });
        } 
        // Fix tooltip not work
        $('body').tooltip({
          selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]'
        });
    });
```

My table

This where I want to echo that data...

```html
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="card-box table-responsive">

                            <table id="datatable-responsive" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Dep't Name</th>
                                        <th>Description</th>
                                        <th>Consultancy Amount</th>
                                        <th>Doctor's Amount</th>
                                        <th>Manage Department</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody id="category-row">
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- end col -->
                </div>
                <!-- end row -->
```

My Contoller now

admin/departments

```
 public function departments()
{

    $table ='';

    $departments = $this->admin_model->departments();

    if(count($departments)>0)
    {
      foreach ($departments as $dept)
      {
        $table.='<tr id="row-id-'.$dept->Dept_id.'">';
        $table.='<td>'.$dept->Dept_name.'</td>';
        $table.='<td>'.$dept->Description.'</td>';
        $table.='<td>'.$dept->Consultancy_amount.'</td>';
        $table.='<td>'.$dept->Doctor_Percentage.'</td>';
        $table.='<td>';
        $table.='<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalUpdate"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-toggle="tooltip" title="EDIT DEPARTMENT"></i></a> |';
        $table.='<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalDelete"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" data-toggle="tooltip" title="DELETE DEPARTMENT"></i></a>';
    $table.='</td>';
    $table.='</tr>';
      }
      echo json_encode($table);     
   }
}
```

What exactly happens is that the window opens with the load_category() function. 
However, when I access it, it comes as JSON just as below

```
"ENT<\/td>Ear, Nose and Throat<\/td>30000<\/td>40<\/td><\/i><\/a> |<\/i><\/a><\/td><\/tr>Cancer<\/td>Cancer<\/td>100000<\/td>50<\/td><\/i><\/a> |<\/i><\/a><\/td><\/tr>ENT<\/td>Ear<\/td>40000<\/td>34<\/td><\/i><\/a> |<\/i><\/a><\/td><\/tr>"
```

I am totally confused about why it cant run the success funtion and echo my data into where I want it.

Thank you very much

Comment: //view depts
    public function departments()
    {
         $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM department");
        
        return $query->result();
    } //This is my model function

Comment: You are clearly returning HTML, not JSON. Remove `json_encode` and change `dataType` to `'html'`. The error is because you're telling jQuery to deserialize a JSON response, yet it errors are it's encoded HTML.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, thanks but I changed according to your instruction but instead I get ENTEar, Nose and Throat3000040 |ENTEar, Nose and Throat3000040 |CancerCancer10000050 |ENTEar, Nose and Throat3000040 |CancerCancer10000050 |ENTEar4000034 | .... The whole thing is the success: function(){//some code like above but it doesnt work...}

Comment: Why don't you create an array on PHP side with the for loop, json_encode it and on the front end JSON.parse the response text and on JS side just go through an each loop on this JSON parsed element.

Comment: @DiabloSteve, thanks for the advice but can you give me a sample just so I can understand you more?... Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The whole problem was that I was loading JQuery at the bottom not at the top. This handicapped me as I could access it.

I concluded that if ypu load jquery right at the bottom, Please use this:

```
 (function($) {

//All your functions go here. Be it Ajax!

        }(jQuery));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you want to do an .html() output on a table body (`$('#category-row').html(data);`), so that might be where your problem lies.  If you are wanting to add rows, I think you need to do an append.

```
$("#category-row").append(data);
```

Also, I might suggest a different method of parsing the data. I would return the whole `$departments` result via the json_encode, and then parse through that in the success function like my example below.  In that example, I am also changing your controller's usage of count and going with *if not empty* (`!empty($departments)`).

**Controller function:**

```
public function departments()
{
    $departments = $this->admin_model->departments();

    if(!empty($departments)) {
        echo json_encode($departments);     
    }
}
```

**jQuery 'success' adjustment:**

```
success: function(data){
    var tableRows = '';

    $.each(data, function(index, dept) {

        tableRows = tableRows + '<tr id="row-id-' + dept.Dept_id + '"><td>' + dept.Dept_name + '</td><td>' + dept.Description + '</td><td>' + dept.Consultancy_amount + '</td><td>' + dept.Doctor_Percentage + '</td><td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalUpdate"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-toggle="tooltip" title="EDIT DEPARTMENT"></i></a> | <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalDelete"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" data-toggle="tooltip" title="DELETE DEPARTMENT"></i></a></td>/tr>';

    });

    $("#category-row").append(tableRows);
}
```

More food for thought...if you want to test that the success is firing at all, put a simple alert('success'); or console.log('success') in there and see if it fires off.  Maybe your query is empty.

Anyway, hope this helps.

Comment: ,Thank you bro for the suggestions. I tried an 'alert' on success but it didn't fire. The problem is not json coming, the real problem is : The call is made, using the URL...but on successful response, it doesn't fire whatever is in:      `success: function(data){
              //$('#category-row').html(data); alert('Why Can't I work?')
            },error: function(){
              alert('Error....');
            }`    Thats the real problem.... Like why????

Comment: Can you pull this up directly in your app and get a result on screen?
index.php/admin/departments

Comment: Yes... that works flawlessly... My issue is: I must use Ajax... for some reason.... `//Link to departments
     public function departments()
    {

        $table ='';

        $depart['departments'] = $this->admin_model->departments();

        if(count($depart)>0)
        {
          $this->load->view('backend/admin/departments',$depart);
    }` and then on my view `<tbody id="category-row">
                                  
                                  
                                    foreach ($departments as $dept)
   `

Comment: maybe double-check that the URL is actually outputting like you want it to?  Maybe the base_url doesn't have the slash at the end, and thus the url being used doesn't exist.  `<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/admin/departments`  
Fire off an alert before the ajax fires to see what the URL actually is.  sometimes to try anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much bro... Let me try it. Blessings

Comment: In your JS, where do you actually call this:  `load_category()`?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      // Load category when page load
      window.onload = function(){
        load_category();
      };</script>`    ... JQuery is included... As to why it doesn't work, I am puzzled... I even fired an alert like `<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      // Load category when page load
      window.onload = function(){
       alert('Loaded');
      };

    </script>` and wow... It simply doesnt alert nothing!

Comment: In looking at that, you have a JS error.  you aren't ending your `$(document).ready(function()` correctly.  It is missing the parenthesis.  It should be:  `$(document).ready(function() { alert('Loaded'); });`  My theory now is that things aren't firing because of an error in your JS related to this or something else.

Comment: To double-check if JS errors are happening elsewhere, use the Inspector on Firefox or the Developer tools in Chrome, and go to the console tab.  That will tell you if you have any other errors going on.

Comment: Thanks so very much... It actually worked now... I used ajax and javascript... The only issue now is that actually loads data intoa datatable but my datatables loose functionality on being populated!... Otherwise, al good... Blessings